# utilizando ÚNICAMENTE preg_replace() + REGEX se puede ELIMINAR lo hallado en \$1?

Tags: php, regex

éste código me entrega "a la perfección" lo que quiero eliminar:

```
$s = 'DATA<td class="td1">111</td><td class="td2">222</td>DATA';
$x = '@<\w+(\s+[^>]*)>@is';
preg_match_all($x, $s, $Q);
print_r($Q[1]);
```

en el índice [1] obtengo las cadenas objetivo:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  class="td1"
        [1] =>  class="td2"
    )
```

de ello concluyo que la "REGEX" es correcta, (me equivóco?).

Ahora bien,
utilizando **únicamente** la función `preg_replace` + la REGEX `@<\w+(\s+[^>]*)>@is` cómo puedo ELIMINAR lo obtenido en "la prueba" anterior?

definitivamente no es posible utilizando **únicamente** `preg_replace` + la REGEX `@<\w+(\s+[^>]*)>@is` ??

ésto no funciona:

```
$nueva_cadena = '';
$Q = preg_replace($x, $nueva_cadena, $s);
print_r($Q);
```

por que la cadena objetivo está en [1], tengo un error al utilizar la función `preg_replace` ó realmente `preg_replace` es una función muy limitada?

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que modificar la `regex` para crear 3 "sub-patrones" de referencia:

- Uno para capturar la apertura del tag (*eg: `(<\w+) => "<td"`*)
- El que ya tenes (*eg: `(\s+[^>]*)`*)
- Y por ultimo el cierre del tag (*eg: `(>) => ">"`*)

#### Ejemplo:

```php
$s = 'DATA<td class="td1">111</td><td class="td2">222</td>DATA';
$x = '@(<\w+)(\s+[^>]*)(>)@is';
$Q = preg_replace($x, '$1$3', $s);
print_r($Q);

// Salida
// DATA<td>111</td><td>222</td>DATA
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/412d8)</kbd>

---

Referencia:

- [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo @Marcos, tu código funciona 100% bien. En éste caso, la función **preg_replace** tiene CUATRO índices ( [0], [1], [2], [3] )? está cambiando el [0] ó el [2]?

Comment: Te recomiendo leer la documentación. La respuesta a tus preguntas está ahí, puntualmente en [`Parámetros -> replacement`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-parameters)